# Amcharts 4 TreeMap bullet link

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, amcharts, treemap

I have one level treemap from amcharts4.

I'm trying to set a link for each bullet when click on it, but can't achieve what I want.

As documentation says I tried:

```
level1_bullet.label.url = "https://www.google.com/";
```

or

```
level1_bullet.url = "https://www.google.com/";
```

both doesn't work, I was able to add

```
level1_bullet.label.html = "<a href='https://google.com/'>{name}</a>";
```

but there is a problem with truncate option which doesnt work and I can see too big names for smallest bullets, wrap also didn't help.

Comment: Can you provide a more full code snippet or a demo where we can see this? I am unable to replicate this issue. See this [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/437bc66815163e900495307a1ae71f7c/) where `bullet1.label.url = "https://www.google.com/";` works just fine.

Comment: Thanks mate I had to update amcharts from npm now eveything works.

Comment: how can I concatenate each bullet url with its name from data? bullet1.label.url = "/example/" + "{name} doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn a `LabelBullet` into a link, try:

```
level1_bullet.label.url = "https://www.google.com/";
```

If we want dynamic urls, we'll have to use [an adapter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/). The `url` is a simple string that's not really intended for display, so it doesn't go through [our string formatting](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-strings/), which means placeholders like `{name}` won't get parsed. Fortunately `Label`s have [an adapter for their `url`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#url_adapter). It can look something like this:

```
level1_bullet.label.adapter.add("url", function(url, label) {
  var query = "";
  var data = label.dataItem;
  if (data.dataContext && data.dataContext.name) {
    query = "?q=" + data.dataContext.name;
  }
  return url + query;
});
```

The adapter's handler has the `url` that's set to the `Label` (`"https://www.google.com/"` in this case) as the first argument and the `Label` instance as the second argument. What we `return` ends up being our custom-formatted `url`, i.e. it doesn't set it permanently, this is run every time your app is figuring out what the value for `url` should be.

I've created a demo here:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/79194dfcfccaa05f5ebe20e1095f3087

Let me know if this makes sense, if this at all helps with what you were looking to do.

Comment: @JanuszAmi btw, I have created a feature request for this over on GitHub, if interested please subscribe:
https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/468

Comment: @JanuszAmi  As of today, with beta.61, [databinding placeholders in `url`s](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Placeholders_in_URLs) is now supported, e.g. `level1_bullet.label.url = "/example/{name.urlEncode()}";`. Please be sure to clear your cache / update amCharts v4 packages.